# Gaming JavaScript / JSON linking text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, json, game-development

I am working on a game and have run into a bit of an issue.  Right now I have a text box that displays that says run into me to continue to the next level.  When I run into it, the next level loads perfectly, that part works great.  Now I am trying to change it up a bit where the text box displays and has two links to two different levels.  There are items in the game and what I am wanting to do is have the player go to one level if he has an item and go to a different level if he does not have an item.  I would do this by giving an item a value, then upon collision with the text box, check to see if that value is in the inventory or not.  So the main question is, is possible to link two nodes to one text box?  If so, how can I go about doing that?  Here is some of my code:

From my .js file:

```
function Choice(scene, text, image, width, height, z) {
// Static textbox object that holds the text of a choice
tChoice = new TextBox(scene, image, width, height);
tChoice.text = text;
tChoice.choiceNumber = 0;
tChoice.z = z;

return tChoice;
} // end choice
```

From my .html file:

```
function checkChoiceCollisions() {
// If a player collides with a choice, that choice's level will be displayed.
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i ++) {
    if(player.collidesWith(choices[i])) {
        player.visible = false;
        switchNode(i);
    } // end if
} // end for
} // end checkChoiceCollisions
```

JSON:

```
"options":[{"text":"Run into me to continue\nto the next level","link":"nodes/nextLevel.txt","width":"150", "height":"75", "x":"800", "y":"250"}]
```

Thanks for any help!!

Edit:  I forgot to add this portion of code..

```
function makeChoices() {
    // Makes the choice textboxes defined by the level.
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i ++) {
        // Destroy the previous level's choice boxes.
            var index = spriteList.list.indexOf(choices[i]);
            spriteList.list.splice(index, 1);
        } // end for
        choices = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < curNode.options.length; i ++) {
        // Create each choice box defined by the level.
            var width = parseInt(curNode.options[i].width);
            var height = parseInt(curNode.options[i].height);
            var x = parseInt(curNode.options[i].x);
            var y = parseInt(curNode.options[i].y);

            var choice = new Choice(scene, curNode.options[i].text, null, width, height, 2);
            choice.setPosition(x, y);
            choice.fitText();
            choices.push(choice);

            if (!checkChoiceRequirements(i)) {
            // Only display a choice if its requirements are met.
                choices[i].visible = false;
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end makeChoices
```

Comment: If there is a better way to go about doing this, please let me know.  It will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this as a question, as I lack points to comment…

Because your function "Choice" is capitalized, I would expect it to be a pseudoclassical constructor, which would then return its implicit 'this' object by default. But instead you're returning 'tChoice', which could have unintended consequences.

You're also defining values for a 'tChoice' object without declaring it via the 'var' keyword. Are you intending to access a global variable named 'tChoice'?

Otherwise, I'm unsure what exactly you're asking with "is possible to link two nodes to one text box?" Accessing an object seems like a good way to go. Are you getting an error? Can you post your code to a Fiddle/Plunkr/JS_Bin?

Comment: The function Choice is being used to simply allow for a text box to appear.  tChoice = new TextBox uses a game library that I added.  Should have explained that.  It should not really have any effect on what I am trying to do though.  As far as the question of whether or not I can link two nodes to one text box goes, I have defined node in my JSON code as moving to the next level which is simply a text file that decides how everything appears.  In order to go to the next level the player interacts with the text box (runs into it).  I would like to have two levels linked to the text box.